# python csv file add a comma on date and time

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I trying to write a code using python with pandas for csv file.
I am trying to add comma on this date set 20200625045500

for example table.csv on

```
 id_posts date_time   f_categories f_user_name  
 80   20200625045500  2CB    johntest
 81   20200725045500  2CaB    johntest
 82   20200805045500  2CsB    johntest
 83   20200725045500  2CdB    johntest
 84   20200625045500  2C4B    johntest
```

output:

```
 id_posts date_time     f_categories f_user_name  

 80   2020-07-25,04:55:00  2CB     johntest
 81   2020-09-25,04:55:00  2CaB    johntest
 82   2020-07-25,04:55:00  2CsB    johntest
 83   2020-01-20,04:55:00  2CdB    johntest
 84   2020-07-15,04:55:00  2C4B    johntest
```

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r'table.csv')
print(data)
```

Comment: if you convert yo string `.astype(str)` then you can use string functions like `df.date_time = df.date_time.str[:4] + '-' + df.date_time.str[4:6] + '-' + df.date_time.str[6:8] + ',' + ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here it is with the code that will run over your dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.read_csv(r'table.csv')
data['date_time'] = data['date_time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S').strftime('%Y/%m/%d,%H:%M:%S'))
print(data)
```

Let me know if this was useful.

Comment: Can you update your answer to include how this applies to the [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas-dataframe) that was read in from the CSV, rather than the single python string `a`?

Comment: how do I connect to my table.csv file rather then entering a string a = '20200625045500'

Comment: I have updated the answer to apply for the dataframe generated by the csv.